# Twython to extract tweets

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am using Twython twitter API to extract tweets. But I am getting 100 tweets only. I want to extract tweets from 10Dec 2013 to 10March 2014. I have mentioned count=1000 in the search function.

The rate limit is 100 I get that. Is there a way to get those tweets between the given period of time without any rate limit.

```
 from twython import Twython
 import csv
 from dateutil import parser
 from dateutil.parser import parse as parse_date
 import datetime
 from datetime import datetime
 import pytz

 utc=pytz.UTC

 APP_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'    
 APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
 OAUTH_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxx'  # Access Token here
 OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'  

 t = Twython(app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET, oauth_token=OAUTH_TOKEN,      oauth_token_secret=OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

 search=t.search(q='AAPL', count="1000",since='2013-12-10')
 tweets= search['statuses']


 for tweet in tweets:
     do something
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a limitation while accessing the tweets through `Search API`. Have a look at this [Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).

> The `Search API` usually only serves tweets from the past week.

As you're trying to retrieve the tweets from past 3/4 months, you are not getting the old tweets.

Comment: Is there any other way out?

Answer (score 1):

With Twython, the search API is limited but I have had success just using get_user_timeline.

I solved a similar problem where I wanted to grab the last X amount of tweets from a user.

If you read the documentation, the trick that worked for me is keeping track of the id of the last tweet I read and reading up until that tweet on my next request using max_id.

For your case, you would just need to modify the while loop to stop on some condition for 'created_at'. Something like this could work:

```
# Grab the first 200 tweets
last_id = 0
full_timeline = 200
result = t.get_user_timeline(screen_name='NAME', count = full_timeline)

for tweet in result:
    print(tweet['text'], tweet['created_at'])
    last_id = tweet['id']

# Update full timeline to see how many tweets were actually received
# Full timeline will be less than 200 if we read all the users tweets
full_timeline = len(result)

# 199 cause result[1:] is used to trim duplicated results cause of max_id
while full_timeline >= 199:
    result = t.get_user_timeline(screen_name='NAME', count = 200, max_id = last_id)

    # Since max_id is inclusive with its bound, it will repeat the same tweet we last read, so trim out that tweet
    result = result[1:]
    for tweet in result:
        print(tweet['text'], tweet['created_at'])
        last_id = tweet['id']

    # Update full_timeline to keep loop going if there are leftover teweets
    full_timeline = len(result)
```